# Call common function in destructor before destroying derived members

Tags: c++, c++11

Assuming we have the classical Base class and derived class like this

```cpp
class B {
public:
    virtual ~B() {
        // calling it here is too late, see explanations
        //common_pre_cleanup_function();
    }

    void common_pre_cleanup_function() { }
};

class D : public B {
public:
    virtual ~D() {
        // What if we forget to do this call in another derived class?
        common_pre_cleanup_function();
    }
};
```

How would you make sure a function like `common_pre_cleanup_function()` is called in all derived `D`s destructors before the members of `D` are destroyed but without having to explicitly call this function in every destructor-implementation of a new `D`?

### Background

In my current project we have a base class that implements certain parallelism and threading features and will eventually start a new thread that does the actual work.
In the destructor of this base class we wanted to make sure, that the thread is always stopped and joined so that it gets cleaned up properly.

However derived classes may create members that are used by this thread in the base class. So if we destroy objects of the derived class, these members are also destroyed. But at this time the thread that is managed by the base class can still be running and now wrongfully access destroyed members.

I'm aware that this isn't the smartest approach to solve the issue and probably splitting up the threading/parallelisation parts and the "actual work" parts into separate classes might be the much smarter idea. However I'm interested if there are any approaches that don't involve an entire rewrite of the existing code base.

This code here is closer to our situation

```cpp
class BackgroundTask {
public:
    virtual ~BackgroundTask() {
        // if we forget to call stop() in the derived classes, we will
        // at this point have already destroyed any derived members
        // while the thread might still run and access them; so how/where
        // can we put this call?
        //stop();
    }

    void stop() {
        cancelFlag_.set();
        thread_.join();
    }

    // more functions helping with Background tasks

private:
    Thread thread_;
    Condition cancelFlag_;
};

class MyTask : public BackgroundTask {
public:
    virtual ~MyTask() {
        // with the current case, we have to remember to call
        // this function in all destructors in classes derived
        // from BackgroundTask; that's what I want to avoid
        stop();
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> member;
};
```

Comment: *"splitting up the threading/parallelisation parts and the "actual work" parts into separate classes might be the much smarter idea"* - it definitely is. With proper class responsibilities such an issue wouldn't occur.

Comment: You violate in general the owning concept. Any entity should be responsible for exactly its own resources, fully independent of what it is. This means not only memory and threads but absolutely include them!

Comment: how about CRTP?

Comment: @Jarod42 Base dtor is still invoked after the derived subobject is dead. Just knowing what derived function to call isn't enough - you have to call it earlier

Comment: Would be better to fix the root cause of having this design issue. It's backwards!

Comment: Any derived class that own some ressource should do its own cleanup. **Base class should only cleanup things from its own class**. Avoid design than goes against basic rules of how C++ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply you don't. The best thing to do in this situation is to redesign how everything works to prevent this from being a problem.

But lets face it, in all likelihood you don't have the time and/or resources to achieve that. So your second best option (in my opinion) is to ensure that any call to the destroyed members of the derived class kills you application immediately with a very clear error message.

If a system must fail, fail early.

Comment: As tough as this answer might be, I have to accept the broad hint that ultimately the underlying design is simply flawed. I guess sometimes you just need an outsider to confirm your naging feelings that something is wrong ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You might do something like:

```
template <typename TaskImpl>
class Task final : public TaskImpl
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<BackgroundTask, TaskImpl>);
public:
    virtual ~Task() { stop(); }
};
```

And then

```
class MyTaskImpl : public BackgroundTask
{
    // ...
private:
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> member;
};

using MyTask = Task<MyTaskImpl>;
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with comments that the design is flawed .....

Assuming that the objects are dynamically allocated, one solution is to make the destructors `virtual` and `protected`, and use a separate function to take care of calling the "pre-cleanup" before destroying the objects.   For example;

```
class B
{
   public:

      void die()
      {
           common_pre_cleanup_function();
           delete this;
      };

  protected:
     virtual ~B() {};

  private:

     void common_pre_cleanup_function() { };
};

class D : public B
{
   protected:
     virtual ~D() {};
};


int main()
{
     B *b = new D;

     b->die();
}
```

This has a few limitations for the user of the class.   In particular, behaviour is undefined if

1. the object is not created using a `new` expression;
2. any non-static member function of the object is called after calling `die()`
3. any non-static data member is accessed after calling `die()`

This also means that, if you maintain a set of objects (like a vector of pointers, `B*`) then it is necessary to remove the pointer from the list to ensure no usage of the object after it has died.

The `protected` destructors  prevent a few things.  Functions that are not members of `friend`s of `B` or `D` cannot;

1. Create a `B` or a `D` of automatic storage duration
2. Use operator `delete` directly.    For example, a statement `delete b;` in `main()` above will not compile.   This also prevents destroying an object before calling the "pre-cleanup"

Answer (score -1):

**Edit: I realized this doesn't aswer your question but I'll leave it here for reference.**

As mentioned earlier, each object should be responsible for managing its own resources so your design is a bit flawed to begin with.

Consider the following example. The `TaskRunner` is responsible for firing up a thread, and shutting it down when the constructor is called (textbook RAII). The `Task` class specifies what to do during the lifetime of the task, through pure virtual inheritance.

```
#include <atomic>                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#include <future>                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                 
#include <memory>                                                                                                                                                                                                   

struct Task {                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    virtual void run( ) = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                        
    virtual ~Task( ) {                                                                                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                               
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

class TaskRunner final {                                                                                                                                                                                            
    std::unique_ptr<Task> task;                                                                                                                                                                                     
    std::future<void>     fut;                                                                                                                                                                                      
    std::atomic<bool>     terminate;                                                                                                                                                                                

public:                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    TaskRunner(std::unique_ptr<Task>&& task)                                                                                                                                                                        
        : task {std::move(task)}                                                                                                                                                                                    
        , terminate {false} {                                                                                                                                                                                       
        fut = std::async(std::launch::async, [this] {                                                                                                                                                               
            while(!terminate) {                                                                                                                                                                                     
                this->task->run( );                                                                                                                                                                                 
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            this->task.reset( );                                                                                                                                                                                    
        });                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                               

    TaskRunner(TaskRunner&&) = delete;                                                                                                                                                                              
    TaskRunner& operator=(TaskRunner&&) = delete;                                                                                                                                                                   
    TaskRunner(const TaskRunner&)       = delete;                                                                                                                                                                   
    TaskRunner& operator=(const TaskRunner&) = delete;                                                                                                                                                              

    ~TaskRunner( ) {                                                                                                                                                                                                
        terminate = true;                                                                                                                                                                                           
        fut.wait( ); // Block until cleanup is completed                                                                                                                                                            
        std::cout << "~TaskRunner()" << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                               
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

struct MyTask : public Task {                                                                                                                                                                                       
    int i = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                      

    void                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    run( ) {                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        // Do important stuf here, don't block.                                                                                                                                                                     
        std::cout << "MyTask::run() " << i++ << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                          
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds {100});                                                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                               

    ~MyTask( ) override {                                                                                                                                                                                           
        // Clean up stuff here, run() is guaranteed to never be run again                                                                                                                                           
        std::cout << "~MyTask()" << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                      
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                               
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

int                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
main( ) {                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    TaskRunner t {std::make_unique<MyTask>( )};                                                                                                                                                                     
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds {1});                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

Output

```
MyTask::run() 0
MyTask::run() 1
MyTask::run() 2
MyTask::run() 3
MyTask::run() 4
MyTask::run() 5
MyTask::run() 6
MyTask::run() 7
MyTask::run() 8
MyTask::run() 9
~MyTask()
~TaskRunner()
```